# ¿Calcular las horas entre una fecha de inicio frente a una final? Java

Tags: java, datetime

Quisiera saber cómo retornar la cantidad de horas entre 2 fechas. Por ejemplo, iniciamos con las 10 y la final 13. Hasta ahí ningún problema, porque son el mismo día, pero si planteo de la siguiente forma. Iniciamos con 20 y la hora final es 2 del día siguiente.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CalculatorApplication.class, args);
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
    int semana = date.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    String mes = date.getMonth().toString();
    int minutos = date.getMinute();
    int dia = date.getDayOfMonth();
    int hora = date.getHour();
    int anio = date.getYear();
    int hFinal = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(0).getHour();
    int actual = date.minusHours(4).getHour();

    int calculator = hFinal - actual;
    System.out.println(calculator + " la actual es " + actual + " y la final " + hFinal);

    System.out.println("Son las " + (hora - 12) + " y " + minutos + "pm del dia " + dia + " del mes " + mes + " del anio " + anio + " y nos encontramos en la semana " + semana);
    }
```

Estaré pendiente a sus contribuciones, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int difHora = 0;

if(horaFinal >= horaInicial)
{
   difHora = horaFinal - horaInicial;
}
else 
{
   difHora = (horaInicial % 24) + horaFinal;
}
```

Primero preguntamos si la hora final es mayor o igual que la hora inicial, en este caso no hay problemas por tanto efectuamos la resta y obtendremos las horas transcurridas.

Ahora bien si la **horaFinal** es menor que la **horaInicial** esto quiere decir que pasamos de un día para otro y aplicamos entonces el **operador %**, el cual nos devuelve el resto de una división entre dos números, como sabemos que un día tiene **24** horas hacemos lo siguiente:

```
difHora = (horaInicial % 24) + horaFinal;
```

Ejemplo:

horaInicial = 20

horaFinal = 2

Nos quedaría:

```
difHora = (20 % 24) + 2;
```

20 % 24 = 4 por tanto:

```
difHora = 4 + 2;
difHora = 6;
```

Comment: Creo que tu respuesta es más directa, soluciona un problema que quería solucionar, te agradezco mucho. **Gracias por todo.**

Answer (score 0):

Muy largo todo. Comparar dos Instant y obtener la duración de la diferencia es más sencillo.

```
import java.time.*;

public class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant one = Instant.now();
    Instant two = ZonedDateTime.now().minusHours(4).toInstant();

    // Puedes usar ChronoUnit para el tiempo total y luego dividir por 60 los segundos, por ejemplo
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(two, one) + " horas (total)");
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(two, one) + " minutos (total)");
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(two, one) + " segundos (total)");

    //Puedes usar Duration
    Duration res = Duration.between(two, one);
    System.out.println(res);

    //Puedes usar Period para períodos largos, días meses o años
    Period period = Period.between(two.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(), one.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    System.out.println(period.getYears() + " años, " + period.getMonths() + " meses, " + period.getDays() + " días");

   }
}
```

Duration va a mostrar un resultado como `PT-4H0.386S`.

ChronoUnit como se muestra allí obtiene como salida

```
3 horas (total)
239 minutos (total)
14399 segundos (total)
```

Period sólo funciona con unidades más grandes: `0 años, 0 meses, 1 días`